# How does this Perl grep work to determine the union of several hashes?

Tags: perl, grep

I don't understand the last line of this function from [Programming Perl 3e](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000271).

> Here's how you might write a function that does a kind of set intersection by returning a list of keys occurring in all the hashes passed to it:
>
> ```
> @common = inter( \%foo, \%bar, \%joe );
> sub inter {
>     my %seen;
>     for my $href (@_) {
>         while (my $k = each %$href) {
>             $seen{$k}++;
>         }
>     }
>     return grep { $seen{$_} == @_ } keys %seen;
> }
> ```

I understand that `%seen` is a hash which maps each key to the number of times it was encountered in any of the hashes provided to the function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) will take a list passed to it (in this case, every element seen in any of the hashrefs); and return a list of only those elements where the expression in the block is true (locally setting `$_` variable to each element in the list).

Let's look at how that expression is evaluated:

- `@_` is an array of all the parameters passed to the subroutine - in our case a list of hash references passed in.
- In `$seen{$_} == @_` expression that list is forced into a [scalar context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) (due to `==`).
- When used in a scalar context, a list evaluates to the number of elements in a list - in the example call above, to 3, since 3 hashrefs were passed in.

So, for each key in `%seen` (e.g. each key seen in any of N hashrefs); the expression `$seen{$_} == @_` is numerically comparing the # of times the element was seen in the hashes to the total number of hashes - it's only going to be equal, of course, if the element is in ALL the hashes that were passed in, and thus a member of the intersection we want.

So, to sum up the analysis, the grep will return a list of all keys **that occur in EVERY hash** (aka occur N times where N is the # of hashes). E.g. an intersection.

Comment: Excellent. Saved my day. I actually wrote a code snippet to understand what is going on and was banging my head to almost an hour but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep block list
```

This will apply block to each element of list in turn, the element is aliased as $_.  If the block returns true, the element is added to the returned array.

in this case:

```
grep { $seen{$_} == @_ } keys %seen
```

The block is `$seen{$_} == @_` , which compares the value of the seen hash against `@_` .  `@_` is evaluated in scalar context and thus returns the number of elements in the `@_` array.  `@_` represents the arguments to the current function.  In this case `( \%foo, \%bar, \%joe )`, which returns `3` in scalar context.  Our list is `keys %seen`, which is an array containing all the keys present in `%seen`.

equivalent english statements:

- "give me a list of all the keys from
  `%seen` where the value associated with
  that key is equal to the number of
  elements passed to this function"
- "give me a list of all the keys from
  `%seen` where the value associated with
  that key is `3`"
- "give me a list of
  all the keys from `%seen` that have
  value `3`, ie all the keys from `%seen`
  that are present in each of the 3
  hashrefs passed to this function"

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the function is to find the elements that appear in all the hashes passed to it.

The last line `grep`s the list returned from `keys %seen`. To determine if a given key appears in all the hashes that were passed to the function, we can compare that key's value in `%seen` to the number of arguments to `inter`.

In the `grep` block, `$_` is set to each element of the `keys` list, and tested for some condition.

An array in scalar context evaluates to its length. `@_` is the array of arguments passed into the subroutine. And the `==` operator puts its operands in scalar context, so we can just compare the value of `$seen{$_}` to the length `@_`. If they're the same, then that key appeared in all the hashes.