# Fastest way to check duplicate columns in a line in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a file with 1 million lines like this

```
aaa,111
bbb,222
...
...
a3z,222 (line# 500,000)
...
...
bz1,444 (last line# 1 million)
```

What I need to check is whether second value after comma is unique or not. If not then print out the line number. In example above it should print out

```
Duplicate: line: 500000 value: a3z,222
```

For this I am using perl and storing value of second column in an array. If I don't find a value in the array I add it to it. If the value already exists then I print it out as a duplicate.

The problem is the logic I am using is super slow. It takes anywhere from 2-3 hours to complete. Is there a way I can speed this up? I don't want to create an array if I don't have to. I just want to check duplicate values in column 2 of the file.

If there is a faster way to do it in a batch-file I am open to it.

Here's my working code.

```
# header
use warnings;
use DateTime;
use strict;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use File::Find;
use File::Slurp;
use File::Spec;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

print "Perl Starting ... \n\n"; 

# Open the file for read access:
open my $filehandle, '<', 'my_huge_input_file.txt';

my $counter = 0;
my @uniqueArray;
# Loop through each line:
while (defined(my $recordLine = <$filehandle>))
{

  # Keep track of line numbers
  $counter++;


  # Strip the linebreak character at the end.
  chomp $recordLine;

  my @fields = split(/,/, $recordLine);
  my $val1=$fields[0]; 
  my $val2=$fields[1]; 

  if ( !($val2 ~~ @uniqueArray) && ($val2 ne "") )
  {
        push(@uniqueArray, $val2);
  }
  else
  {
    print ("DUP line: $counter - val1: $val1 - val2: $val2 \n");
  }

}

print "\nPerl End ... \n\n";
```

Comment: `If not then print out the line number.` of the second and any later lines with that value?  or the first too?  or just the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's one of the things a hash is for

```
use feature qw(say);

...

my %second_field_value;

while (defined(my $recordLine = <$filehandle>))
{
    chomp $recordLine; 
    my @fields = split /,/, $recordLine;

    if (exists $second_field_value{$fields[1]}) {
        say "DUP line: $. -- @fields[0,1]";
    }
    ++$second_field_value{$fields[1]};
}
```

This will accumulate all possible values for this field, as it must. We can also store suitable info about dupes as they are found, depending on what needs to be reported about them.

The line number (of the last read filehandle) is available in [$. variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$.); no need for `$counter`.

Note that a check and a flag/counter setting can be done in one expression, for

```
if ($second_field_values{$fields[1]}++) { say ... }  # already seen before
```

which is an idiom when checking for duplicates. Thanks to ikegami for bringing it up. This works by having the [post-increment](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) in the condition (so the check is done with the old value, and the count is up to date in the block).

I have to comment on the smart-match operator (`~~`) as well. It is widely understood that it has great problems in its current form and it is practically certain that it will suffer major changes, or worse.  Thus, simply put, I'd say: don't use it. The code with it has every chance of breaking at some unspecified point in the future, possibly without a warning, and perhaps quietly.

---

Note on performance and "computational complexity," raised in comments.

Searching through an array on every line has *O*(*n* *m*) complexity (`n` lines, `m` values), what is really *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) here since the array gets a new value on each line (so *m = n-1*); further, the whole array gets searched for (practically) every line as there normally aren't dupes. With the hash the complexity is *O*(*n*), as we have a constant-time lookup on each line.

The crucial thing is that all that is about the size of input.  For a file of a few hundred lines we can't tell a difference. With a million lines, the reported run times are "*anywhere from 2-3 hours*" with array and "*under 5 seconds*" with hash.

The fact that "complexity" assessment deals with input size has practical implications.

For one, code with carelessly built algorithms which "runs great" may break miserably for unexpectedly large inputs -- or, rather, for realistic data once it comes to production runs.

On the other hand, it is often quite satisfactory to run with code that is cleaner and simpler even as it has worse "complexity" -- when we understand its  use cases.

Generally, the complexity tells us how the runtime depends on size, not what exactly it is. So an *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) algorithm may well run faster than an *O*(*n* *log* *n*) one for small enough input. This has great practical importance and is used widely in choosing algorithms.

Comment: no way! your code worked the entire file in under 5 seconds. bravo and thank you!

Comment: @SamB  Well, good -- it's a nod to the value of the notion of "computational complexity" :).  Searching through an array on every line ... it's `O(nm)` (`n` lines, `m` array values) which is really `O(n^2)` since `m`-array has a distinct value on each line so _`m` is `n`_; with the hash it's `O(n)`.  The key to this is -- it starts to matter with `n` large enough, and you've got that with a million lines ...

Comment: @SamB   ... so at line 10 it's a 9-long array that's searched and on line 11 it's a 10 long array ... but at line 1_000 the array has that many elements ... and count how it goes at 100_000, and beyond. Another nasty bit here is that it does search through the _whole_ array every single time, since there aren't many dupes there (presumably).  If you were up for it you could print timing information out (every 1_000 or 10_000 lines say), to see how this develops

Comment: The check and the flag setting can be combined: `if (!$second_field_value{$fields[1]}++)` This is a common idiom for finding duplicates

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash. Arrays are good for storing sequential data, and hashes are good for storing random-access data. Your search of `@uniqueArray` is O(n) on each search, which is done once per line, making your algorithm O(n^2). A hash solution would be O(1) (more or less) on each search, which is done once per line, making it O(n) overall.

Also, use `$.` for line numbers - perl tracks it for you.

```
my %seen;
while(<$filehandle>)
{
  chomp;
  my ($val1, $val2) = split /,/;

  # track all values and their line numbers.
  push @{$seen{$val2}}, [$., $val1];
}

# now go through the full list, looking for anything that was seen
# more than once.
for my $val2 (grep { @{$seen{$_}} > 1 } keys %seen)
{
  print "DUP line: $val2 was seen on lines ", join ", ", map { "$_[0] ($_[1]) " } @{$seen{$val2}};
  print "\n";
}
```

This is all O(n). Much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The hash answer you've accepted would be the standard approach here. But I wonder if using an array would be a little faster. (I've also switched to using `$_` as I think it makes the code cleaner.)

```
use feature qw(say);

...

my @second_field_value;

while (<$filehandle>))
{
    chomp; 
    my @fields = split /,/;

    if ($second_field_value[$fields[1]]) {
        say "DIP line: $. -- @fields";
    }
    ++$second_field_value[$fields[1]];
}
```

It would be a pretty sparse array, but it might still be faster than the hash version. (I'm afraid I don't have the time to benchmark it.)

**Update:** I ran some basic tests. The array version **is** faster. But not by enough that it's worth worrying about.